# How in leaflet add custom data to polyline?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

In jquery 3/leaflet / turf app 
I use custom class extended from CircleMarker
as I need in any marker keep info about any point and info on nearby points.
Markers are connected with polylines and I want to keep simialr information polyline
and clicking on it get this info. I failed to make it. I do

```
    customCircleMarker = L.CircleMarker.extend({
        options: {
            first_market: false,
            last_market: false,
            point_id: null,
            prior_point_id: null,
        }
    });
    var selectedPoint= {}
    var points = [
        {id: 1, title:'title #1 ', lat:52.509, lng:-3.08},
        {id: 2, title:'title #2 ', lat:51.503, lng:-1.06},
        {id: 3, title:'title #3 ', lat:49.51, lng:-2.47}
    ];

    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 7);


    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1
    }).addTo(mymap);

    drawPoints()
    function drawPoints() {
        let polylinePoints= []  // I get all info about all Polylines
        let loop_index =  0
        points.forEach(point => {
            let priorPoint= null
            if(loop_index > 0) {
                priorPoint= points[loop_index - 1]
            }

            var myMarker = new customCircleMarker([point.lat, point.lng], {
                title: 'unselected',
                radius: 20,
                first_market: loop_index == 0,
                last_market: loop_index == points.length-1,
                point_id: point.id,
                prior_point_id: priorPoint ? priorPoint.id : null,
            });
            myMarker.on('click', function (event) { // THAT WORKS OK
                console.log('myMarker.event.target.options.point_id::')
                console.log(event.target.options.point_id)
            });
            myMarker.addTo(mymap);

            polylinePoints[polylinePoints.length]=[point.lat, point.lng]
            loop_index++
        })


        var radius = 10;
        var polyline = new L.Polyline(polylinePoints, {
            color: 'green',
            opacity: 1,
            weight: 2,
            customData:{  // BUT TAT DOES NOT WORK AS POINT IS OUT OF LOOP
                point_id: point.id,
                prior_point_id: priorPoint ? priorPoint.id : null,
            }
            // offset: radius
        });
        // Add click listener
        polyline.on('click', function (event) {
            event.originalEvent.stopPropagation();
            window.event.cancelBubble = true;  // CAN NOT STOP Propagation
            showModal(event)
            // alert('Polyline clicked!');
        });
        // Add polyline to featuregroup
        polyline.addTo(mymap);

        // zoom the map to the polyline
        mymap.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());

    } // function drawPoints () {
```

How can I add custom data to polyline ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to extend the CircleMarker class to add more options. You can do this at the default way:

```
var myMarker = L.circleMarker([point.lat, point.lng], {
                title: 'unselected',
                radius: 20,
                first_market: loop_index == 0,
                last_market: loop_index == points.length-1,
                point_id: point.id,
                prior_point_id: priorPoint ? priorPoint.id : null,
            });
```

Also don't use `polylinePoints[polylinePoints.length]=` if it is not necessary. Use `polylinePoints.push(`

---

What do you want with the data on the polyline? Why you not adding the whole point array to the polyline?

```
var polyline = new L.Polyline(polylinePoints, {
            customData:{  
                points: points
            }
        });
```

Else you can create a array of the point ids:

```
let polylinePoints= []  // I get all info about all Polylines
let loop_index =  0;
let pointIds = [];
points.forEach(point => {
   pointIds.push(point.id);
 //...

var polyline = new L.Polyline(polylinePoints, {
            customData:{  
                points: pointIds
            }
        });
```

Or (what I recommand) to add the markers to the polyline:

```
let markersForPoly = [];
points.forEach(point => {
 //... Loop ...
 myMarker.addTo(mymap);
 markersForPoly .push(myMarker);
});

//.. Code

var polyline = new L.Polyline(polylinePoints, {
            customData:{  
                points: markersForPoly 
            }
        });
```

---

And the you can get the points in the click listener:

```
polyline.on('click', function (event) {
     var layer = event.target;
     var points = layer.options.customData.points;
     console.log(points);
});
```

**Example**
https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/61sjx3bv/

Comment: Thanks !
As I can see custom data are added to al polylines:
var polyline = new L.Polyline(polylinePoints, {
            customData:{ 
            
I need for any polyline define start point (with marker) and wnd point (with marker)
when clicking on any polyline defined these points(with markers)

Comment: In your example you have only one polyline object, where are the "other" polylines? Or do you mean the line between the to markers? Then you can create a own polyline object and add them only the two markers.

Comment: Yes, clicking on line between 2 markers I need to get access to markers on start and end of this line.
Pls exaample how cam I do this.

Comment: I added you a example (click on the marker or the polyline), I hope you check my answer as correct ...

Comment: Thanks!
    But could you please to give some explanations . Looks like you
    create polyLines one by one and setting lastMarker and myMarker to 
    markers propery. But what markers propery really is here ? Standart polyline propert or like custom value?

Comment: I added them. the markers property is a custom property